# How to set a range with cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to set a range to fit width columns, but I would like to set using numbers, no letters, something like this:

```
myWorksheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 13)).Columns.AutoFit
```

But I get an error 400.

If I use

```
myWorksheet.Range("A1:M1").Columns.AutoFit
```

It works perfecly.

How I could to use cells to set the range and to do the AutoFit? Because I am using variables to set the range and I can't use letters, I have to use the numbers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, please:

```
myWorksheet.Range(myWorksheet.Cells(1, 1), myWorksheet.Cells(1, 13)).EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

If your active worksheet is not `myWorksheet`, the ranges will belong to the active sheet. Then, `EntireColumn` ca be `Autofit`, not a cells range...

Comment: It is better to use the `.Resize()` modifier. Like `myWorksheet.Range("A1").Resize(1,13).EntireColumn.AutoFit`

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
Sub test()
  
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("myWorksheet")
    
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 13)).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define cells in range..

you can try this

```
Dim Rg1 As Range
Dim Rg2 As Range

    Set Rg1 = Cells(1, 1)
    Set Rg2 = Cells(1, 13)

    Range(Rg1, Rg2).EntireColumn.AutoFit
```